# Obstacle avoidance (in cone)

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a command so the turtles would avoid the green patches in my map.

```
to avoid-obstacle
 let front-patches patches in-cone 5 60
   if pcolor of one-of front-patches = green [set heading heading - 45]
end
```

unfortunately gives me

```
of expected this input to be a reporter block, but got a number or list instead
```

any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying that the command `of` wants a reporter block, which is a code block (in square brackets) that returns something. In this case it wants to get the value of the variable `pcolor` from the specified turtle. Try this (note the brackets around `pcolor`):

```
to avoid-obstacle
 let front-patches patches in-cone 5 60
   if [pcolor] of one-of front-patches = green [set heading heading - 45]
end
```

By the way, it's not going to do exactly what you have described. This code will randomly select one of the front-patches (that's what `one-of` does) and check if it's green. From your description, I think you want to change direction if any of them are green. That would look like:

```
to avoid-obstacle
 let front-patches patches in-cone 5 60
   if any? front-patches with [pcolor = green] [set heading heading - 45]
end
```